# How to make underbracket thinner

Tags: mathtools

Consider this code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
C(s)=\underbracket{\frac{K_1}{s}}_{\text{forced}}+\underbracket{\frac{K_2}{s+2}+\frac{K_3}{s+4}+\frac{K_4}{s+5}}_{\text{natural}}
\]
\end{document}
```

and the result below

[image]

I think the underbracket is too thick. How to make it thinner?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Excerpting from p. 14 of the user guide of the `mathtools` package (highlighting added):

[image]

The user guide says that the default width of underbrackets is ca `5/18ex` = ca. `0.28ex`. The following screenshot shows expressions with underbrackets that involve the default width as well as one half, two thirds, and three quarters of the default width; choose your favorite.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\underbracket' macro
\begin{document}
\[
% default width: 5/18ex = ca 0.28ex
 \underbracket{1+2+3}_{\text{default}} % default width
+\underbracket[0.140ex]{1+2+3}_{\text{spaghetti}}% (1/2)default
+\underbracket[0.187ex]{1+2+3}_{\text{skinny}}   % (2/3)default
+\underbracket[0.210ex]{1+2+3}_{\text{thin}}     % (3/4)default
+\underbracket[0.280ex]{1+2+3}_{\text{default}}  %      default
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd actually use the default rulethickness of the math font (`\fontdimen8\textfont3`) which would fall in your “anorexic” category.

Comment: Oh no, not at all.  The information about the default line width of `\underbracket` is entirely correct, but it doesn't acutally use the default rulethickness that is defined in the font.  The value of `\fontdimen8\textfont3` is for instance used to draw the fraction bar and is the default height of `\hrule`.

Comment: Done. Thanks Mico. @HenriMenke we are scraping "anorexic" from this answer out of respect for those struggling with anorexia. Could you help us out too?

Comment: Was looking for this, but for some reason none of the size options work for me. I have loaded ``mathtools`` and am using ``beamer``. I do have many other packages loaded. Can you think of a potential incompatibility? Many thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT - Please provide some specific examples of what you’re doing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mico. The problem is that my minimal examples work fine so I haven't been able to find the culprit. Perhaps there's a package out there that defines an `\underbracket` command... Not to worry, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 11):

The thickness of brackets can be specified in the first optional argument of `\underbracket` and `\overbracket`. The default thickness is the height of `$\braceld$` (in current math font).

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  C(s) = 
  % use 0.5 thickness
  \underbracket[.5pt]{\frac{K_1}{s}}_{\text{forced}} + 
  % use default thickness
  \underbracket{\frac{K_2}{s+2}+\frac{K_3}{s+4}+\frac{K_4}{s+5}}_{\text{natural}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also change the thickness of brackets once for all:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% change default thickness of brackets to .6pt
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\xpatchcmd\upbracketfill
  {\sbox\z@{$\braceld$}\edef\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim{\the\ht\z@}}
  {\edef\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim{.6pt}}
  {}{\fail}

\xpatchcmd\downbracketfill
  {\sbox\z@{$\braceld$}\edef\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim{\the\ht\z@}}
  {\edef\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim{.6pt}}
  {}{\fail}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  C(s) = 
  \underbracket{\frac{K_1}{s}}_{\text{forced}} + 
  \overbracket{\frac{K_2}{s+2}+\frac{K_3}{s+4}+\frac{K_4}{s+5}}^{\text{natural}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Can this be used for 'underbrace' and 'overbrace' as well? if so how so?

Comment: @guillermoedgardo No. Braces use the glyphs in math fonts, but brackets are drawn by latex rules.